# Adding editable content to prestashop footer template

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Please help. I need to add editable content (for example company contacts) to prestashop footer template (footer.tpl).

Hardcoding the footer.tpl is no problem but i need to add editable content (via backend).
What is the simplest way to include CMS block content in to the footer.tpl?

Prestashop 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to get one of the free modules and to attach it to "footer" hook.

- http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/172429-free-module-display-multilingual-html-texts-everywhere/
- http://contentbox.org/
- http://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/html-box.html

Note that some of them do not have multi-lingual support - in case you need it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I use htmlbox already the problem is the next: i need to displaying custom content in specific place inside of multicolumn footer (in last column) so the hook_footer linkink is not good for me. I think i need to create a custom hook and put it in the last column inside of footer then linking it with htmlbox

Comment: You can add the hook code in your template: {hook h='displayMyNewHook'} and to attach to it in your module with code like: public function hookDisplayMyNewHook($params) {} and of course transplant it from Modules -> Positions [Transplant]

Comment: thank, in the meantime i solved my problem with contentbox modul. This modul not need a modul modification. I just add a new hook to DB (in table ps_hook) and registered it in frontcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more simple way. You can create page in CMS. Use "CMShomepage" module to get the page content on home page. Footer hook is default. You can find this free module here

http://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/cms-on-homepage.html

You can check the use at
http://bharatkidukan.com